# Validations on click of two buttons

Tags: knockout.js

I have two textboxes of with `value` bindings for two observables: `first` and `second`. There are two save buttons of with `click` bindings to functions `save1` and `save2`.

**Scenarios I should satisfy :**

*For `save1` function:*

1. When I enter something in `first` and nothing is in `second`, and `save1` is clicked: means its should save.
2. when I enter something in `first` and enter a value in `second`, and click `save1`: means its should validate `second` against `first` and make sure `second` is greater than `first`.

*For `save2` function:*

The exact opposite of `save1`, i.e.:

1. When I enter something in `second` and nothing is in `first`, and I click `save2`: means its should save.
2. When I enter something in `second` and enter a value in `first`, and click `save2`: means it should validate `first` against second and make sure `first` is less than `second`.

This scenario looks very straightforward, yet I got blocked moving forward to complete the code. I tried in a fiddle, which basically has code given here (abbreviated to make post readable):

**View Model:**

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self=this;
    self.first=ko.observable();
    self.second=ko.observable();

   //custom validation code & click functions
   self.validatefirst=ko.validatedObservable([
   self.first.extend({//code here}) ])

   self.validatesecond=ko.validatedObservable([
   self.second.extend({//code here}) ])
}
```

**View:**

```html
<label>First value: <input data-bind='value:first'/></label>
<label>Second value: <input data-bind='value:second'/></label>
<input type="submit" value="save first" data-bind="click:save1" />
<input type="submit" value="save second" data-bind="click:save2" />
```

See also [my jsfiddle with complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/nmtoukk7/).

As far I could see I feel like we can't implement this, because there is only single observable where we trying to do multiple operations for two buttons.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used an observable for each button which were set to true if the button was clicked. This is used to only fire the required and number validation which I used in conjunction with onlyIf. Then I added two custom validators on `second()` to perform the comparison check.

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self=this;

    self.first=ko.observable('');
    self.second=ko.observable('');
    self.validateFirst = ko.observable(false);
    self.validateSecond = ko.observable(false);

    self.first.extend({
        required: {
            message: "First is required",
            onlyIf: function () { return self.validateFirst();}
        },
        number: {
            message: "Not a number",
            onlyIf: function () { return self.validateFirst();}
        }
    });

    self.second.extend({
        required: {
            message: "Second is required",
            onlyIf: function () { return self.validateSecond();}
        },
        number: {
            message: "Not a number",
            onlyIf: function () { return self.validateSecond();}
        },
        validation: [{
            validator: function (val) {
                if (!self.validateFirst() || self.second() === '') {
                    return true;        
                }

                var secondInt = parseInt(self.second());
                var firstInt = parseInt(val);
                return secondInt > firstInt;
            },
            message: 'Please enter second value greater than first value'
        },
        {
            validator: function (val) {
                if (!self.validateSecond() || self.first() === '') {
                    return true;        
                }

                var firstInt = parseInt(self.first());
                var secondInt = parseInt(val);
                return secondInt > firstInt;
            },
            message: 'Please enter second value greater than first value'
        }]
    });

    self.save1=function(){
        self.validateSecond(false);
        self.validateFirst(true);

        if(self.isValid()){
            alert('Saved');
        }
        else {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    };

    self.save2=function(){
        self.validateFirst(false);
        self.validateSecond(true);

        if(self.isValid()){
            alert('Saved');
        }
        else {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    };

    ko.validatedObservable(self);
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4c6qLkw/2/)

Comment: thank you for giving it a try but couple of things here mate error message info should come beside `second` if i enter less value in second textbox for `save1` and just a mention not a big one messages on modified is set to true but its not working .

Comment: I updated it. I changed the message to what you had.

Comment: Did this end up solving your issue? If so please don't forget to select my answer as the solution.